# How to convert 1-column dataframe to several columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe:

```
col1
1a
2b
3d
4a
5a
6f
7a
8a
9e
```

How to get that dataframe:

```
col1 col2 col3
1a     2b    3d
4a     5a    6f
7a     8a    9e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy reshape:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.col1.to_numpy(), (-1, 3)), 
             columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

  col1 col2 col3
0   1a   2b   3d
1   4a   5a   6f
2   7a   8a   9e
```

Comment: i edited my question in case if values aren't numerical